# How to resolve loaded but missing

Tags: clearcase

In Clearcase, how do I resolve "loaded but missing" for an element in my snapshot view?

The last thing I did was to delete a branch, for which my config spec was currently using a rule to see.

I've tried deleting the file(rm filename), and updating my snapshot view again, to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: I followed the instructions [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258149).

1. Removed the file(rm file.cpp).
2. 'cleartool get -to /path/to/snapshot/view/file.cpp  file@@/main/myBranch/LATEST'
3. Next, the file was hijacked, so I did a cleartool update but specified to "Rename hijacked files and load selected version from the VOB" as instructed in the instructions [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_undo_hijack.htm),